# Batch file for downloading with WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, authentication, winscp

I have created a batch file to automate the download with WinSCP but it does not work. It is for sure a syntax error. Here is the script. Can you help m? Thanks

> WinSCP.exe sftp://username:password@host/ -hostkey="xxxxxxxxx" -privatekey xxx.ppk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WinSCP.exe sftp://username:password@host/ -hostkey="xxxxxxxxx" -privatekey=xxx.ppk
```

Just from browsing the [documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline) it looks like you forgot the `=` after the `-privatekey` parameter.